# Returned python values break html table after inserting in javascript array

Tags: javascript, python, flask

I am trying to display values returned from a backend python function into an html table by interfacing the python function with XMLHttpRequest(). 1) The table works with javascript array without the python function returned value. 2) The python function call works when the javascript variable is passed to an element id in the html body. 3) It breaks the table when the python returned value is passed to a javascript array to display in the table. Thank you.

module

```py
    class GetName:
        ...
        def get_name():
            return "Johnny Test"
```

flask server

```py
    ...
    @app.route('/record_status', methods=['POST'])
    def get_value():
        json = request.get_json()
        status = json['status']
        if status == "true":
            res = GetName.get_name()
            return jsonify(result=res)
```

```js
    var myJSON;
    // When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
    btn.onclick = function() {
      modal.style.display = "block";

    // XMLHttpRequest
      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
            //var myObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
            var myObj = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);

            myJSON = JSON.stringify(myObj);
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = myJSON;
          // alert(xhr.responseText);
          }
      };
      xhr.open("POST", "/record_status");
      xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type",     "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
      xhr.send(JSON.stringify({ status: "true" }));

      //function GenerateTable() {
                //Build an array containing Customer records.
      var customers = new Array();
      customers.push(["Customer Id", "Name", "Country"]);
      customers.push([1, 'John smith', "United States"]);
      customers.push([2, "Anita Ross", "Canada"]);
      customers.push([3, myJSON, "Mexico"]);
```

condition 1) and 2) in working order. The table breaks once the var myJSON is inserted in the array

Answer (score 0):

there is a much easier way to go about doing this, you could use ajax from jquery. if you need help figuring it out just reply back or try watching this vid: its how I learned [Click here for vid](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zJdQxS3ZpNI)

Answer (score 0):

The `onreadystatechange` is executed after the `customers` is created. So, your last customer data contains `undefined`.

Looks like you need to move the `customers` array creation to the `onreadystatechange` function.

```js
      xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
          if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
            //var myObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
            var myObj = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);

            var myJSON = JSON.stringify(myObj);
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = myJSON;
          // alert(xhr.responseText);

            var customers = [];
            customers.push(["Customer Id", "Name", "Country"]);
            customers.push([1, 'John smith', "United States"]);
            customers.push([2, "Anita Ross", "Canada"]);
            customers.push([3, myJSON, "Mexico"]);
          }
      };
```

Comment: @riy if you want people to help you, it's better you bring all the information you have. For example, instead of saying "doesn't work" you should say what is the problem or error you are seeing now.

Comment: Well noted, I already tried your solution prior to posting the question and it failed to generate the table. As noted in the post, the table breaks upon pushing the returned var myJSON to the table, thanks.

Comment: @riy this means that you are showing only part of the code. The real problem is the table generation. I assume the code is generating the table before receiving the data from the server. So, showing more code would help. Otherwise, this question should be closed.

Answer (score 0):

Following Avi Baruch's link and some modifications to suit the project, the html is created with ajax to interface with the python function, the response is jsonified within the python function and assigned to a dictionary key called data, while rendering a response template with a variable name myList. The response template allows to loop over the returned data to be passed unto the modal content in `<div id="dvTable"></div>`. Hope someone finds this useful, thanks all.

```
#get_data.py : backend module return values 

class GetData:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def records(self):
        return [(1, 'John Smith', 'Canada'),
                (2, 'Jane Doe', 'United States'),
                (3, 'John Doe', 'Mexico')]
```

```
#app.py

from flask import Flask, render_template, jsonify
from get_data import GetData
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/_get_data/', methods=['POST'])
def _get_data():
    data = GetData()
    myList = data.records()
    return jsonify({'data': render_template('response.html', myList=myList)})

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

```html
<!--templates/index.html-->
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <style>
body {font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}

/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
  display: none; /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
  padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%; /* Full width */
  height: 100%; /* Full height */
  overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 80%;
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
  color: #aaaaaa;
  float: right;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
</style>
    </head>

    <body>
 <!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
<button id="myBtn">Open Modal</button>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <div id="dvTable"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<style>
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td, th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
</style>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU="
  crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>

<script>
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];


// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btn.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
  //var Table = document.getElementById("dvTable").innerHTML = "";
  //prevent duplicates
  $("#dvTable tr").remove(); 
       //get the data and append to the table
       $.ajax({
            url: "/_get_data/",
            type: "POST",
            success: function(resp){
                $('div#dvTable').append(resp.data);
            }
        });
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";

}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

```
<!--templates/response.html: layout template to iterate through the data-->

    <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Customer ID</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Country</th>
            </tr>
            {% for elem in myList %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{elem[0]}}</td>
                <td>{{elem[1]}}</td>
                <td>{{elem[2]}}</td>
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
    </table>
```