# HTML <img> tag blocking ajax POST

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I am streaming video to a webpage with Flask.

1. The video stream works by itself.
2. I then added a modal that interfaces with a python backend function and gets data to display.
3. The modal displays the returned data from the python function.
4. Once I activate the html `<img>` tag streaming the video and the modal at the first time, the video stream blocks the ajax POST and hence the modal fails to display the data.

condition 4) fails. Seems the `<img>` tag is blocking the ajax POST.

**This code is a continuation of a prior post I submitted and answered few days ago** `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57067923/returned-python-values-break-html-table-after-inserting-in-javascript-array`

This is a complete code to reproduce my error, thanks in advance.

```
# project/get_data.py: python backend module that return data to be displayed in a modal table

class GetData:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def records(self):
        return [(1, 'John Smith', 'Canada'),
                (2, 'Jane Doe', 'United States'),
                (3, 'John Doe', 'Mexico')]
```

```
# project/camera.py : camera module that returns encoded frames

import cv2

class VideoCamera(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.video = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

    def __del__(self):
        self.video.release()

    def get_frame(self):
        ret, frame = self.video.read()
        if ret:
            ret, jpeg = cv2.imencode('.jpg', frame)
            return jpeg.tobytes()
```

```
<!-- project/templates/index.html -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <style>
body {font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}

/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
  display: none; /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
  padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%; /* Full width */
  height: 100%; /* Full height */
  overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 80%;
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
  color: #aaaaaa;
  float: right;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
</style>
    </head>

<body>
        <!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
<button id="myBtn">Open Modal</button>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <div id="dvTable"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<style>
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td, th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}

</style>

<br><br>

<!--video feed, uncomment the <img> tag to reproduce error===-->

<!--<img id="vid" src="{{ url_for('video_feed') }}">-->

<!--video feed ==============================================-->

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU="
  crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>

<script>
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];


// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btn.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
  //var Table = document.getElementById("dvTable").innerHTML = "";
  $("#dvTable tr").remove(); 
       $.ajax({
            url: "/_get_data/",
            type: "POST",
            success: function(resp){
                $('div#dvTable').append(resp.data);
            }
        });
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";

}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

```
<!--project/templates/response.html-->

    <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Customer Id</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Country</th>
            </tr>
            {% for elem in myList %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{elem[0]}}</td>
                <td>{{elem[1]}}</td>
                <td>{{elem[2]}}</td>
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
    </table>
```

```
# project/app.py : flask framework

from flask import Flask, render_template, Response, jsonify
from camera import VideoCamera
from get_data import GetData

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/_get_data/', methods=['POST'])
def _get_data():
    data = GetData()
    myList = data.records()
    return jsonify({'data': render_template('response.html', myList=myList)})

def gen(camera):
    """Video streaming generator function."""
    while True:
        frame = camera.get_frame()
        yield (b'--frame\r\n'
               b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + frame + b'\r\n\r\n')

@app.route('/video_feed')
def video_feed():
    """Video streaming route. Put this in the src attribute of an img tag."""
    return Response(gen(VideoCamera()),   
                    mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

**How to Reproduce error**

1. The `<img>` tag in `templates/index.html` is currently commented out:

```
<!--video feed, uncomment the <img> tag to reproduce error===-->

<!--<img id="vid" src="{{ url_for('video_feed') }}">-->

<!--video feed ==============================================-->
```

2. run `python app.py`
3. open localhost:5000 in browser and click on `open modal` and you should see the `get_data.py` returned customer information in working state.
4. Stop the flask server with `Ctrl+C`. Uncomment the `<img>` tag in `templates/index.html` and connect a camera to your PC and run `python app.py` for the second time. click the `open modal`, it fails to get the data to create the table in the modal.

Expected result is to show the modal content while the video is streaming. Currently, the only way to show the result is when the `<img>` tag is disable, thank you.

Comment: Are you able to provide a reproducible example? We've got an incomplete script and an `<img>` tag.

Comment: @t8tortotlover Thank you for your response, I have provided a complete reproducible example and better formatting.

Comment: I think you should push some workable project on git, if you are concern with privacy, then create a private repo, So that code is accessible and, someone, who want to help, can reproduce the scenario

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to this issue:
1) updating to flask to 1.1.1 fixed the issue without any changes to the code.

2) An alternate solution is to forgo the ajax request and `template.html` and make following changes:

```
<!-- project/templates/index.html -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <style>
body {font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}

/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
  display: none; /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
  padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%; /* Full width */
  height: 100%; /* Full height */
  overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 80%;
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
  color: #aaaaaa;
  float: right;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
</style>
    </head>

<body>
  <!-- OPEN THE CONTENT WHEN USER CLICKS MODAL-->
<button id="myBtn" onclick="document.getElementById('myModal').style.display='block'">Open Modal</button>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <div id="dvTable">
      <!-- INSERT THE TABLE IN THE MODAL-->
      <table>
       <table>
        <tr>
          <th>Customer Id</th>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Country</th>
        </tr>

        <tr>
        <!-- loop through data -->  
        {% for elem in myList %}
        <tr>
          <td>{{elem[0]}}</td>
          <td>{{elem[1]}}</td>
          <td>{{elem[2]}}</td>
        </tr>
        {%endfor %}
        </tr>

    </table>

    </table>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<style>
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td, th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}

<br><br>

</style>

<img id="bg" src="{{ url_for('video_feed') }}">

<!--<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU="
  crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>-->


<script>
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

//AJAX POST COMMENTED OUT
/* 
// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btn.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
  //var Table = document.getElementById("dvTable").innerHTML = "";
  $("#dvTable tr").remove(); 
       $.ajax({
            url: "/_get_data/",
            type: "POST",
            success: function(resp){
                $('div#dvTable').append(resp.data);
            }
        });
}
*/
// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";

}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

```
# project/app.py

from flask import Flask, render_template, Response, jsonify
from camera import VideoCamera
from get_data import GetData

app = Flask(__name__)



@app.route('/')
def index():
    # get the data and render it to the index page with a variable
    data = GetData()
    myList = data.records()
    return render_template('index.html', myList=myList)

""" NO LONGER NEEDED TO SERVE DATA TO AJAX POST
@app.route('/_get_data/', methods=['POST'])
def _get_data():
    data = GetData()
    myList = data.records()
    return jsonify({'data': render_template('response.html', myList=myList)})
"""
def gen(camera):
    """Video streaming generator function."""
    while True:
        frame = camera.get_frame()
        yield (b'--frame\r\n'
               b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + frame + b'\r\n\r\n')

@app.route('/video_feed')
def video_feed():
    """Video streaming route. Put this in the src attribute of an img tag."""
    return Response(gen(VideoCamera()),   
                    mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Hope this help others.